# Converting CSV data read in to PowerBI field

Tags: r, powerbi

Hi I've imported this R script into PowerBI and need to convert it so it reads from the data table which is:

Update_Date (date type) / Series (string type) / Milestone_Finish_Date (date type)

An example of the data imported would be

01/12/2023  A Data Point Name 13/12/2023

01/01/2024  A Data Point Name 20/12/2023

It makes a very boring line diagram with a triangle over it.

However it's throwing a wobbly and frankly whilst I assume this is fairly simple, can anyone provide assistance as it's doing my head in.

```html
# The following code to create a dataframe and remove duplicated rows is always executed and acts as a preamble for your script: 

dataset <- data.frame(Milestone_Finish_Date, Series, Update_Date)
#dataset <- unique(dataset)

# Paste or type your script code here:
data = dataset
str(data)
library(ggplot2)

#setwd("C:/R-File")
#data <- read.csv("Data.csv")

# Convert string dates to actual date objects
data$Update_Date <- as.Date(data$Update_Date, format = "%d-%b-%y")
data$Milestone_Finish_Date <- as.Date(data$Milestone_Finish_Date, format = "%d-%b-%y")



# Create the milestone trend analysis chart with colored triangle area
ggplot(data, aes(x = Update_Date, y = Milestone_Finish_Date, group = Series)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = Series), show.legend = TRUE, lwd = 1) +  # Set show.legend to FALSE
  geom_point(size = 1, show.legend = FALSE) +  # Set show.legend to FALSE
  geom_polygon(data = data.frame(
    x = c(min(data$Update_Date), max(data$Update_Date), max(data$Update_Date), min(data$Update_Date)),
    y = c(min(data$Milestone_Finish_Date), min(data$Milestone_Finish_Date), max(data$Milestone_Finish_Date), min(data$Milestone_Finish_Date)),
    Series = rep("", 1)
  ), aes(x = x, y = y, fill = Series), alpha = 1, color = "grey", lwd = 1.1, show.legend = FALSE) +  # Add a black border line
  labs(title = "Milestone Trend Analysis Chart",
       x = "Update Date",
       y = "Milestone Finish Date") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "top") +  # Remove legend title
  guides(color = guide_legend(title = "Series")) +  # Replace "Series" with your desired legend title
  scale_fill_manual(values = "white")  # Set the polygon fill color to white
```

Comment: What's the error. It looks like you are doing a basic csv import. Use get data /power query to import it, you can format the column as a date, then it will be a dataset in power bi that you can reference in the visual. don't load it via the visual if you have to

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jon, the script does originally read in as a CSV for testing - that code which does work is now commented out.  However the data is already imported in via the powerBI server, so I need to use the data which is already available.  I assumed this would be simple to switch over, but I'm obviously doing something wrong.

Comment: Error is "Error: object 'Update_Date' not found"

Comment: In true "here you go I fixed it, for anyone else with this problem you must not change the sections of automatically generated text above the "#paste or type your script code here".  All I needed to change was data = dataset and change the code back to the original autogenerated code.  Daft programming moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer for this issue for anyone struggling.

Do not modify any of the rows in the R editor above the "Paste or type your script code here:"

To replace a .csv read in, you only need to change the "data <- read.csv("Data.csv")" to data = dataset.  Job done.  No need to parse as a str(data) either or modify the data fields with formatting as that's done in PowerBI already.